# Get field from XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, children

I am trying to extract some fields from a XML file in PHP. This works for most of the fields, but a few of them are giving me errors and I don't understand why.

XML example:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <ns2:name>Some name</ns2:name>
    <offers>
      <offer id="123">
        <ns2:productUrl>https://www.something.here</ns2:productUrl>
        <priceHistory>
          <ns2:price currency="EUR">299.00</ns2:price>
        </priceHistory>
      </offer>
    </offers>
  </product>
</products>
```

I already have the name:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($products->product->children('ns2', true)->name);
```

I wanted to do the same for price and ProductUrl but that doesn't work:

```
$URL = $products->product->offers->offer->children('ns2',true)->productUrl;    
$price = $products->product->offers->offer->priceHistory->children('ns2', true)->price;
```

Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work and how I can get the producturl and price?

Comment: What does "that doesn't work" mean? Those lines should return the correct elements, see https://eval.in/924453

Comment: You might want to look at http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php perhaps

Comment: First error is Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. Second error is Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on null.

Both on the line of getting $URL. Script doesnt go further after the second error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Seems there were two children on top-level. First one without any data. That's what caused the error. Received null and wanted to get children of null, which did not work obviously.